# number box not firing event on keyup when value is 0

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

In my view I have an event like this:

```
events: {
      'click .po_total .updates_total': 'updateTotal',
      'focusout .po_total .updates_total': 'updateTotal',
      'keyup .po_total .updates_total': 'updateTotal'
}
```

The haml JSHTML is:

```
%input.span2#shipping.updates_total{type: "number", name: "shipping", min: "0.00", step: "0.01", value: "0.00"}
```

Here is the code for Update:

```
updateTotal: function(e) {
  if(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
  this.$el.find('.po_total #total').html(this.getOrderTotal());

  if (Application.Helpers.currencyToValue(this.$('#total').html()) > 0 ) {
    this.watchTotal(e);
  }
},
```

The problem is that the `updateTotal` event does not fire when the value is changed to 0.  It works all other times, but not when it is 0.  I need it to work when the value is 0 because there is  conditional behavior that happens in `updateTotal` when the value is 0 that currently never happens.

How can I get an event to fire when the value changes to 0?

Comment: The code you've pasted here isn't relevant.  We need to see the code for `updateTotal`.

Comment: I will post it up, but my issue is the function is not being fired, not the code within the function.  Even if the function is just:  updateTotal:  function(){alert('doing stuff');} it does not work

Comment: added the code up top

Comment: I see a "total > 0" if() statement in there. Are you sure the function is actually not being called, rather than being called and then not doing anything because you're looking for a value > 0?

Comment: I am positive.  Like I said above, I have changed the function to function(){alert('doing stuff');} and tried to debug on the first line and it still does not work

Comment: I am confident that it is something with the events not firing

Comment: If the event is not firing, it is not Backbone.  Here is jsFiddle showing keyup working with '0'. http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/6qkXm/5/

Comment: thanks for the fiddle.  I did not think of isolating it like that, I am going to see if it will help me solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that for some reason the events where not being initialized properly because of the .po_class.  Although the dom structure was correct, this did not work for elements with 0 as the value.  I removed that class, and now it works